# How can I optimize loading images from URL for uicollectionview?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I didn't know that uicollection view always calls the method **(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath**

When you move the cells, so my program then always calls loading of images from url. Making it slow.

Comment: Asynchronously load the images and cache them.

Comment: use SDWebImageCache for the same. If the image will be downloaded then next time it will fetch it from cache instead of making call to server everytime

Answer (score 4):

You can use SDWebImage for your purpose with cache support. You need not to be download a image that already fetched before.

Just visit https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage and use it.

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012177-CH1-SW14)...

```
– dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
```

Call this method from your data source object when asked to provide a new cell for the collection view. This method dequeues an existing cell if one is available or creates a new one based on the class or nib file you previously registered.

**Important**: You must register a class or nib file using the registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier: or registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier: method before calling this method.

**EDIT**: I assume you're loading the images asynchronously if not then use the following code.

```
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
  [NSURL URLWithString:@"ur image url"]]]];
  dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [[cell imageView] setImage:image];
     [cell setNeedsLayout];
  });
  });
```

**EDIT 2**: atomk's suggestion(below comment) makes sense,so i won't be posting the code here.In replacement you can use the library called [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).You can load as many images you want and the same URL won't be downloaded several times as per the author of the code.

Comment: @atomk.thanks for the NOTE...i will edit the answer now...

Comment: @atomk Really? Thought the whole point of GCD was to abstract away thread creation in such a way. Do you have any further reading on that?

Comment: @atomk..is there any documentation available on that?...i too have the feeling like GCD will take away such things...

Comment: `dataWithContentsOfURL` is blocking, so until its done, its thread is blocked, which means GCD has to create more threads if its trying to perform 50 blocking calls at once. `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` is GCDs abstraction so that you can use the threads run loop to perform multiple request asynchronously on the same thread.

Comment: @atomk..any links on the same is greatly appreciated...thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685623/issue-with-gcd-and-too-many-threads

Comment: @BaloniBoi..welcome..Please do accept it as the answer in case it worked for you...thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Load your images using `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` then use NSCache to prevent downloading the same image over and over. Look here for an example, you may even want to include this AFNetworking library and use it: 
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/UIImageView%2BAFNetworking.m

Comment: Thanks Atomkm, I did use AFNetworking but it's too big for a simple app I am making.