# ImageView loads local image but not from URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I am having trouble getting an image to load from a URL.  I have `CollectionViewCell` subclass with an image view setup like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *albumCover;
```

I cannot get it to load images from a URL.  Here is the code im using:

```
NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: song.albumURL]];
cell.albumCover = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData: imageData]];
```

Meanwhile, this works:

```
cell.albumCover.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lock.png"];
```

I know the URL connection is getting the proper image back because I am monitoring it with Fiddler.  Why isn't the image showing up then?

Comment: Check this link


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506744/taking-time-to-load-the-image-from-url-to-uiimageview/18507182#18507182

It may help you

Answer (score 3):

I was allocating the `UIImageView` object again instead of just initializing it with the image.  The correct code is:

```
NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: song.albumURL]];
[cell.albumCover initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData: imageData]];
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [`SDWebImageView`](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage):

> Asynchronous image downloader with cache support with an UIImageView category
>   http://hackemist.com/SDWebImage/doc

Comment: SDImageview also does so much more awesome stuff, like build it animated gifs!

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`fileURLWithPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/fileURLWithPath%3a) instead of the `URLWithString:`.

`URLWithString:` is for WWW URL.

And an example:

```
NSString *rootPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString *filePath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"example.mov"];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];
yourMoviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: fileURL];
```

Comment: thanks but i think you misunderstood what im trying to do...I am trying to load an image from the internet.