# Images load table is very slow

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

i am getting data from server that contains some images i get properly from url and set it to the tablview cell correctly done.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    AppDelegate * delegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text=[delegate.firstArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"%@",delegate.thirdArray);

    url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[delegate.thirdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

    data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];

    UIImage * img=[UIImage imageWithData:data];

    cell.imageView.image=img;

    return cell;
}
```

in delegate.thirdArray  contais this url

```
 "http://awe.com/app/images/can.png",
"http://awe.com/app/images/card.png",
"http://awe.com/app/images/tp.png",
"http://awe.com/app/images/tricks.png"
```

images load properly but it will take some time to load that image and scroll the tableview it will very slow i want it to be fast how may i do this.

Comment: This question does't match your Reputation level ...anyways try Lazy Loading...

Comment: h kishan can you please help me to sort out this..

Comment: I would suggest you to first fetch all the images completely then add them on the tableView..

Comment: check my answer your problem will be solved

Comment: Fetch all image first is correct but how may i add then it to tablview cell..

Comment: check my answer in it you can fetch images while tableview reload.  Not need to pre fetch all images.

Comment: I think this question is asked at least once each day

Comment: @JitendraDeore use async imageview

Comment: @BhaveshNai i used async imageview and  this will work fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to load images asynchronously so tableview can load fast here in your code tableview take so much time because it load image for every cell.

Please check below answer you can find how to load images asynchronously.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15377082/1713478

Please change url with your url

hope your problem will solved.

Comment: **synchronically** is an incorrect word in this context. The word is **synchronously**. Btw link you mention suggests OP to load images **asynchronously**. Please edit.

Comment: thanks Amar for suggestion. :)

Comment: i tried your solution and work fine for me thanks...

Comment: pls change synchronously to asynchronously...

Comment: negative votes welcome but please let me know reason for negative marking.

Answer (score 3):

Load your images using `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` then use **NSCache** to prevent downloading the same image again and again.

As suggested by many developers go for [**SDWebimage**](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) and it does include the above strategy to download the images files .You can load as many images you want and the same URL won't be downloaded several times as per the author of the code

Example on *`[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`*

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your_URL"];
NSURLRequest *myUrlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: myUrlRequest queue: queue completionHandler: ^ (NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{

    if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil)
        //doSomething With The data

    else if (error != nil && error.code == ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT)
        //time out error

    else if (error != nil)
        //download error
}];
```

Then use [NSCache](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html)...

For further explanation: [READ HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506744/taking-time-to-load-the-image-from-url-to-uiimageview)

Answer (score 0):

Download AFNetworking from this link

> https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

and then add files to your project and then in .m file

```
#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    AppDelegate * delegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text=[delegate.firstArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"%@",delegate.thirdArray);

    url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[delegate.thirdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];



    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Yes, AFNetworking's UIImageView extension makes this nice and easy

Answer (score 0):

Another answer is to use the amazing SDWebImage framework. It will load your images asynchronously and cache them so if the user has to load the same image again he won't have to download it again.

Here is the link to the framework :

```
https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage
```

Here is the code for your cell :

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    AppDelegate * delegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text=[delegate.firstArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"%@",delegate.thirdArray);

    url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[delegate.thirdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url];
    // [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]]; if you want to add a placeholder image

    return cell;
}
```